# VMware: error-'CPU disabled by guest operating system' after I move the VirtualMachine folder?

Tags: vmware

I used 'squeeze' (cite program - URL?) to compress a VMWare virtual machine. I also moved the VM files. Now, when attempting to start the VM, I get `CPU disabled by guest operating system`

What caused this error and how can I recover my VM?

Comment: Cite the program you used to 'squeeze'.
Cite the commands you used to squeeze, move, move back, and unsqueeze.

This may be a simple problem to fix. Asking good questions is hard work, though.